# I am trying to control 4 servos with a joystick, but after a few seconds, they start spinning and don't stop until the power source is cut

Tags: servo, joystick

Here's my code. I don't know if the issue is the power source though. I only have access to my computer for a power source.

```
#include <Servo.h>
  
Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
Servo servo3;
Servo servo4;

int joyX = A2;
int joyY = A5;
int Joyx = A2;
int Joyy = A5;
  
int servoVal;
  
void setup() 
{
  servo1.attach(A0);
  servo2.attach(A1);
  servo3.attach(A3);
  servo4.attach(A4);
}
  
void loop()
{
  
  servoVal = analogRead(joyX);
  servoVal = map(servoVal, 0, 1023, 0, 180);
  servo1.write(servoVal);
  delay(15);

  servoVal = analogRead(joyY);
  servoVal = map(servoVal, 0, 1023, 70, 180);
  servo2.write(servoVal);
  delay(15);

  servoVal = analogRead(Joyx);
  servoVal = map(servoVal, 0, 1023, 0, 180);
  servo3.write(servoVal);
  delay(15);

  servoVal = analogRead(Joyy);
  servoVal = map(servoVal, 0, 1023, 70, 180);
  servo4.write(servoVal);
  delay(15);  
}
```

Comment: If you think it is a current limitation problem (power) try only controlling 1 servo (disconnect the other servos).  Also check you are using common servos and not continuous servos.

Comment: how are the joysticks connected? ... your code indicates that you may be shorting out your power supply

Comment: Why are you reading twice from each joystick acis (since `joyx` and `joyX` are defined with the same pin)?

Comment: ... Ah! Nice catch @chrisl.

Comment: @jsotla I have the joystick connected to the A2 pin. I am quite a noob to this and would appreciate if you could explain what in my code could be shorting out my power :(

Comment: your code shows `joyx` and  `joyX` ... that indicates two joysticks ... both are connected to pin A2 ... if you turn one joystick to maximum and the other joystick to minimum, then that provides a low resistance path between Vcc and GND through the common connection at A2